# Why does Google Analytics show more users than sessions?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

My Google Analytics page shows almost twice as many Users than Sessions. It really doesn't make sense to me, does anybody know what's the reason for this?

Here is a snapshot from my GA dashboard:
[image]

Comment: Yeah. It does not make sense to me either. Welcome to Googlieland!

Comment: None of my websites have more users than sessions according to Google Analytics.  I don't know why that would be the case for your site.

Comment: Is this a custom report/using any custom dimensions or parameters or the complete unaltered default?

Comment: It's the default report, it's completely unaltered.

Comment: @Lirik,only custom report shows more Users than Sessions.can you please update or edit your question with more information, so we can understand what's happing here.

Comment: I have taken [a screenshot of my customs report screen](http://i.imgur.com/2Wgb2KJ.png), but we haven't done any custom reporting.

Comment: @SudheeraNjs I don't know what would cause this, the ONLY thing that we have is some custom goals on which we're reporting events. However, the issue has been occurring even before setting up the custom goals.

Comment: @Lirik the Users graph shows a spike in users. Is that a day, week, or month. Can you pinpoint that time frame and determine what caused the spike? What type of traffic was it, direct, referral, etc?

Comment: @Anagio are you suspecting that the spike caused the discrepancy between the users and the session? Because the problem seems to have been occurring since the website was launched.

Comment: @Lirik yes I would look to rule that out. That spike in the mini graph may be hundreds or thousands of users in a short time period. At least determine the source of traffic for that spike.

Comment: @Anagio the spike on Jun 10 was due to us sending a notification e-mail on Jun 9. We enabled 2FA and a ton of people flocked the website, mostly direct and organic traffic. However, I'm still not sure how that relates to the problem we're seeing since the discrepancy existed even before the spike.

Comment: @Lirik install Tag Assitant by Google in Chrome see if there are any warnings or errors

Comment: @Anagio I installed the tag assistant, but no errors or warnings were found. Single tag on the website: www.bitlendingclub.com

Comment: @Lirik If you click suggestions it shows `Suggestion: Non-standard implementation` this also links to a resource at Google https://support.google.com/tagassistant/answer/3059154?ref_topic=2947092#non_standard

Comment: @Anagio thanks for pointing that out... any info on how we can use a standard implementation? The article is very brief on this subject.

Comment: Here is [Universal Analytics documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/), there is the standard snippet.  
The only difference I can see is the third parameter when calling `create`:  
`ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', 'yourdomain.com');`  
Standard is:  
`ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', 'auto');`  
Maybe you need to track multiple subdomains and your snippet should be:  
`ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', {'cookieDomain': 'yourdomain.com'});`

Comment: I have the same problem and I really need an answer to this question! :(

Answer (score 10):

For those that land on this question where they experience more users than sessions in Audience Overview (I.e. no custom report or hit level dimensions concerned, which seems to crowd out search results when researching this issue) ask this:

1. Are you running events on your website?
2. Are those events on iframes or sub domains?
3. Are you firing events on landing pages that load before the pageview tag?

I learned this today. If you have events that fire on an iframe but no pageview tag on the iframe, then a new user is generated in Google Analytics on the back of that event, but no new session.

The prescribed way to get around this is to add the iframe or subdomain name to the referral exclusion list in Admin > Profile > Tracking info. However, that currently seems buggy since I had done that and not working as expected and I still saw this issue.

Regarding the 3rd point, if your visitors are landing, triggering an event and then bouncing before the pageview tag fires it may under report sessions. For example, one of our clients pageview tags, configured in Google Tag Manager, waits for the page to load before firing since we want the crm system to finish loading so we can grab some data and feed as a custom dimension into GA.

This is not actually my answer, you are getting it second hand via me from [here](https://plus.google.com/+GavinCameronP/posts/QL7pnUXBmDc). Read the link for more details. Posting here since I was getting frustrated finding anything on this.

Comment: Welcome back Doug, and thanks for the informative answer.

Comment: Yep - 3rd point in your answer definetly resolves the issue - making UA PageView tag to fire before any UA Event tag brings sessions data back on track. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> If you build a custom report that has page level dimensions (like Page, Page Title, or a page level custom variable) Users might appear greater than Sessions. This may occur when viewing the sessions metric against any sort of page level dimension because sessions are incremented on, and therefore associated with, the first hit of the session.

[Why a custom report shows more Users than Sessions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2934985?hl=en)

Comment: as far as I can tell, I don't have any custom reports. I have several other Google Analytics accounts for our User Acceptance Testing environment (which is identical to the website) and it's showing up just fine.

Comment: This is where I was headed but once @Lirik confirmed it was the default report, I had to jump ship.